# Using Django, South and Sqlite during development

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-south

I'm new to Python (2.7) and Django (1.5) and am working through the [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/) whilst making a hobby site. I'm using Sqlite3 as dev db, but in production I intend to us MySQL. South looks like a great solution for database schema migration management, but it doesn't play well with Sqlite.   I'm now tempted to install MySQL on my dev machine, but wonder if there's a way to avoid that. I'd appreciate knowing a simple, practical solution to this problem, if anyone knows of one.

Edit: I meant a programmatic solution (for those that feel this is off topic). I imagined there may be a way to use Django's settings.py and some custom code to accomplish this.

Comment: No, there isn't anything. Going ahead with SQLLite just prolongs the inevitable. Also I would move from MySQL to PostGresql just because South has better support for it.

Comment: Don't know why it got down-voted, seems a reasonable question. @limelights: Thanks for the Postgresql suggestion, also useful.

Comment: This comment should not be off topic.  I was wondering how to go on with the tutorials as well and the answer below helped me in less than five minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way around this. To use South properly you require complete `ALTER TABLE` support which [SQLite does not have](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html).

This and other small differences will make developing on MySQL a better choice, especially if you plan to deploy to MySQL.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. That sums it up perfectly, thank you!